# image out of sync when scrolling

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So i'm currently learning `ios` and `firebase` and by that I mean how they link to get etc.

So far I have a post table which display all posts.

An individual using the app can like a photo, similar to a facebook like, this then is stored within the user table as shown here:

[image]

Each ID corresponds to a post.

Now the issues I experiencing is when I load the news feed and scroll up and down in the back ground I check if the user has liked this post, if so then I fill the heart image to full other wise leave it empty as shown here:

[image]

And when I say heart empty, I mean it'll be white instead of red.

Now when I scroll up and down on the simulator looking at all the posts, there seems to be a delay in changing the colour, sometimes the post's that I have not liked will have the full heart, then suddenly change to empty and vice versa.

This is my code, I first make a call to firebase to retrieve the likes the user has linked to him, by appending the post.postKey

```
 let likesRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Users").child((FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid)!).child("Likes").child(post.postkey)

 likesRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

    if let doesNotExist =  snapshot.value as? NSNull {

       self.likedImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-empty")


     } else {

        self.likedImage.image = UIImage(named: "heart-full")

     }
    })
```

Can someone shed some light into why the heart image is misbehaving ?

**Update**

As requested, please see below cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = posts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("PostCell") as? PostCell {

        cell.request?.cancel()

        var img: UIImage?

        if let url =  post.imageUrl{
            img = FeedVC.imageCache.objectForKey(url) as? UIImage

        }

        cell.configureCell(post, img: img)

        return cell

    }
    else{
        return PostCell()
    }

}
```

the function cell.ConfigureCell is where this heart code resides.

** Update 2 **

It seems to be when I scroll really quickly the issue exists, however scrolling up and down slowly it works as expected... can anyone thing of a solution for this?

Comment: do you call the above in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: When the news feed is displayed I first make a call to firebase to retrieve all posts, I then use cellForRowAtIndexPath to configure it

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: I've added the function as requested, I also download an image from the web that's dependant on if the user has uploaded one.  However this "like" code lives above the image code

Comment: I am trying to understand what is `self` in `observeSingleEventOfType` method?

Comment: The cell has it's own custom class.  Inside this class resides the IBOutlets for each element in the cell.  The word Self is referring to the IBOutlet declared at the top of the class this is required when referencing the property in a closure.  The custom class is called PostCell which is inside CellForRowAtIndexPath